# Traveling from Haiti to Colombia without a layover in the United States

Tags: usa, air-travel, visa-refusals, visa-bans

I want to leave and travel from Haiti but all flights seem to pass through the United States. I wish to travel to Colombia, DR, Mexico, Brazil, Grenada and Turkey.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Flightconnections](https://www.flightconnections.com/flights-from-port-au-prince-pap) tell us that there should be flights (at least part of the year) not going to or through the US from Port au Prince to:

- Panama City
- Havana and a few other places in Cuba
- Turks and Caicos
- Santo Domingo and Punta Cana in the Dominican Republic
- Sint Maarten
- Pointe à Pitre
- Paris

To get to Colombia you can to travel via Panama, Santo Domingo, Punta Cana, Havana.

To get to the Dominican Republic you can fly or drive or take a bus.

To get to Mexico, again, via Panama, Santo Domingo or Havana, though it depends where in Mexico you want to go.

To get to Brazil, again, Panama, Santo Domingo or Punta Cana.

To get to Grenada, there aren't any obvious options not going via the US.

To get to Turkey, you have options via Panama, Havana, and Paris.

In some cases, it may make sense to travel over land to the Dominican Republic and take flights from there: there are a lot more flights from Santo Domingo and Punta Cana than there are from Port au Prince.

Note that you may need visas for the destination country and possibly for the transit countries, depending on the country and whether you can get a connecting flight on a single ticket.

Note that many booking tools allow you to exclude specific connecting airports